# express-fileupload Upload original when using fileSize limit

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the mentioned fileuplaod middleware. I want to setup a middleware that warns on file size limit exceed but don't want to truncate the file.

```
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 },
    createParentPath: true,
    safeFileNames: true,
    preserveExtension: 5,
    limitHandler: function (req, res, next) {
        Logger.warn("File size limit has been exceeded");
    },
    abortOnLimit: false,
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileDir: './temp/apiuploads'
}));
```

The files are getting truncated. Hence the files that are uploaded cant be opened. I want to log the message when file size limit exceed but don't want to truncate the file. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your current output and your expected one, please?

Comment: I uploaded a pdf file of size 3mb. After upload the size of file became 1mb and as a result the file could not be opened. When I try to open that file it shows file cannot be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add file limits options for the middleware, also I recommend to use middleware only with upload routes.

Check uploaded file size after it has been uploaded with size value.

And log message if size more then your limit.

Example:

```
app.use('/upload', fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true,
    safeFileNames: true,
    preserveExtension: 5,
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileDir: './temp/apiuploads'
}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
    return;
  }

  const uploads = Object.values(req.files).map((file) => {
    if (file.size > 1 * 1024 * 1024) {
      Logger.warn(`File ${file.name} size limit has been exceeded`);
    }
    const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', file.name);
    return file.mv(uploadPath);
  });

  Promise.all(uploads)
    .then(() => res.send('Files uploaded to ' + path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});
```

Comment: Please add code for everyone's use. And for clarity.